# Derivation of Dieterici and Saha-Bose Equations of State

Tags: kinetic-theory, gas

Is there any theoretical background of gas equations of state like

1. Dieterici's equation,i.e

$$P=\frac{RT}{V-b}e^{-a/RTV}$$

2. Saha and Bose equation, i.e.

$$P=-\frac{RT}{2b}e^{-a/RTV}\ln((V-2b)/V)$$

Comment: Are you asking how the equations are derived?

Comment: Are you implying that they are not based on theory?

Comment: No i just want to know how they are derived

Comment: Next time you can save time (yours and ours) just googling it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state

Comment: NB (to all): some of the EOS we have were originally empirically based, rather than theoretically based (e.g., Boyle's law).

Comment: @Willy Billy Williams : I don't think your comment is fair, as that Wikipedia article does not really address the poster's problem properly.

Comment: @StephenG  there are links in the article to similar derivations such as van der waals. But in any case you can google theese two and get some answers. Perhaps I have been a little overreacrive because I have noticed that recently too many people  ask questions without even trying to google things. And I honestly cannot understand why. Might it be the new "siri" generation?

Comment: @willy-billy-williams : I get where you're coming from, believe me.  However the question, in this case, did peak my interest as finding an actual derivation of the Dieterici equation is proving more difficult that I expected.